# Reading csv file using R and RStudio

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a csv file in R, but I am getting some errors.
This is what I have and also I have set the correct path

```
mydata <- read.csv("food_poisioning.csv")
```

But I am getting this error

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe>Y'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls
```

I believe I am getting this error because my csv file is actually not separated by comma, but it has spaces. This is what is looks like:
[image]

I tried using sep="  ", but it didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps try `read.table("food_poisioning.csv", header = TRUE)`. Or maybe `sep = "\t"`

Comment: Seems like this is an encoding issue. It looks like your file is a UTF file with a byte order marker (BOM). Maybe try `mydata <- read.csv("food_poisioning.csv",  encoding = "UCS-2LE")`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Do you know what encoding was used on the file? Where did you get it from? What operating system are you using? You need to know how the file was encoded to open it properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having difficulty using `read.csv()` or `read.table()` (or writing other import commands), try using the "Import Dataset" button on the Environment panel in RStudio. It is useful especially when you are not sure how to specify the table format or when the table format is complex.

For your .csv file, use "From Text (readr)..."
[image: Import Dataset option in Environment Panel]

A window will pop up and allow you to choose a file/URL to upload. 
You will see a preview of the data table after you select a file/URL. 
You can click on the column names to change the column class or even "skip" the column(s) you don't need. 
Use the Import Options to further manage your data.

Here is an example using [CreditCard.csv from Vincent Arel-Bundock's Github projects](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/AER/CreditCard.csv):

[image: Import Text Data window]

You can also modify and/or copy and paste the code in Code Preview, or click **Import** to run the code when you are ready.